# How to get accurate coordinates from google geocoding services?

Tags: google, reverse-geocoding

Can I write my address in a better way to increase the odds of getting better coordinates  from google geocoding services. If someone has insights about how GIS parse addresses or experinces with geocoding services, please share

Comment: So do you want `reverse geocoding` or `geocoding`?

Comment: Sorry I meant geocoding i.e address to coordinates, thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse geocoding can be done using the google reverse geocoding API

Google states

> When geocoding a point in the city of Chicago, the
>   geocoded point may be denoted as a street address, as the city
>   (Chicago), as its state (Illinois) or as a country (The United
>   States). All are "addresses" to the geocoder. The reverse geocoder
>   returns any of these types as valid results.

In addition to saying

> Generally, addresses are returned from most specific to least
>   specific; the more exact address is the most prominent result, as it
>   is in this case

However this isn't always completely true from my personal experience. Just a interesting insight from fiddling around with Google geocoder: Sometimes using a Postcode can provide less accuracy then a single street address (i.e. 12 Evergreen Road, Bristol). For example using Googles reverse geocoder, entering my house number and city gives a more accurate coordinate reference than doing the same with the addition of my postcode. Using just my postcode gives the worst accuracy however. Food for thought

Take a look at the geocoding types for how it classifies address types:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

Other Reading and sources:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResponses

Comment: Last para about geocoding helped. if possible, edit this answer. I meant geocoding only.